# как забрать данные из компонента в родительском компоненте без vuex?

Tags: vue.js, frontend

как забрать данные из компонента в родительском компоненте без vuex?

```
    <v-list-item v-for = "folder in folders" v-bind:key = "folder.id">
      <v-list-item-content v-if = 'folder.id'>
        <dashFolder v-bind:folder='folder'/>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
```

в компоненте dashFolder есть массив, я бы хотел забрать все эти массивы в обьект вида {folder.id : array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В компоненте dashFolder в нужный момент вызываете событие:

```
this.$emit('array-changed', this.myArray);
```

а в родителе его ловите:

```
<dashFolder v-on:array-changed='onArrayChanged'/>

onArrayChanged: function(dashArray) {
  ...
}
```

и там уже собираете в нужном формате.